# Silverlight: VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups doesn't, How can I get them?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visualstatemanager, attachedbehaviors

I've tried using `VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups` in the `OnAttached` override of my custom behavior, as well as in an event handler added to `AssociatedObject.Loaded` event in that behavior. Both times I get an empty list.

Is there another way to get the visual state groups defined for a control, or another event handler I should attach to?

Be for it's asked, yes, the control has `VisualStateGroups` and `VisualStates`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the `VisualStateGroups` attached property is attached to the top level `FrameworkElement` in the control's `ControlTemplate`.  Hence to retrieve this value you may need to use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get the first child of the control and see if that has a `VisualStateGroups` property.

Comment: I went a different way with the code I was working on, but I was wondering, if the Visual state groups are defined at the root of a UserControl, isn't that markup in the .xaml file the control template?

Comment: I tried this approach and the child returned is a Grid, and the visual states are indeed associated with it, however, VisualStateManager.GoToState only accepts controls, and Grid is not a control, so now I have a catch-22 issue and I cannot set the state.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Anthony's answer.
Here I give an example for Metro App.

```
public VisualState GetCurrentState(string stateGroupName)
{
    VisualStateGroup stateGroup1 = null;

    IList<VisualStateGroup> list = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0) as FrameworkElement);

    foreach (var v in list)
        if (v.Name == stateGroupName)
        {
            stateGroup1 = v;
            break;
        }

    return stateGroup1.CurrentState;
}
```